# Sequence generator or Variable Port

Tags: informatica

For sequence generation we can use Sequence Generator and Informatica Variable port. I am just curious about which one is better to use on aspects like performance and etc. Any reference on this from Informatica text will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from performance please keep code readability and maintenance in mind. Sequence Generator is clearly visible just at first glance. Variable ports are hidden and visible only while editing the appropriate expression.

Comment: Conditional increment and automatic restartability are some of the features of Variable port. It seems that this is more of a personal choice as we have no info from Informatica text about the main driving factor here i.e.performance. So closing this.

Comment: remember Sequence generator has a limit a of 2.1 billion.
so eith use a identity column if you are in Teradata or if you are in oracle better to lookup target table get the max(id) and Increment it by adding it with outout of sequence generator.

Answer (score 1):

If you go only by performance, I suspect Sequence Generator will perform better.

However, which approach you should take largely depends on the scenario. For example, if you need to generate a sequence starting from a 0 (or any fixed number) every time the mapping runs, then Sequence Generator will do fine. However, say, you need to generate sequence numbers after the max number present in the target table; in this case, you might do a lookup on target table to get the max value and go on incrementing it in a variable port.

An example where you cannot use a variable port, is when you need to generate unique sequence numbers in multiple mappings. But, you can use a reusable sequence generator for this purpose.

Again, you would go for a variable port, when you need more flexibility in generating sequence numbers, like, to generate a new sequence number, only when a unique value appears in some source column.

Comment: Sir, in simple scenario like generating PK for XML or generating surrogate key which approcah is better or both are same? Which is better in terms of performance or it hardly matters?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I think if you want just continuous sequence you have to use variable port , it will give you better performance and sequence generator creates lots of problems while migration while migration,
if you want certain kind of loop or some special requirement then one should go for sequence generator.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider these points:
1--> Sequence generator is a separate transformation to generate the sequence numbers. Also it has a limit of 2,147,483,647 value after that you would need to take another sequence generator to continue otherwise the mapping fails.
2--> I haven't heard generating sequence numbers using expression transformation has an end value.
3--> If you don't want to have more transformations in the mapping(to avoid mapping complexity) you may generate the numbers using expression transformation itself.
4--> If you consider ease of use, may go with sequence generator since you don't need to do define anything manually as inbuilt it's all set.

For complete guidance please refer to
https://chase4chance.blogspot.com/2022/09/sequence-generator-vs-variable-port-in.html